# Collection of ghost-stories for children/young adult

Tags: story-identification, young-adult

I am looking for a book published in the 90's. It's ghost stories. The book itself has multiple short short stories in it. Maybe 5. I read it when I was in middle school.

One story I remember is a girl was driving home possibly drunk. On her way there she hits something but brushes it off 'cause she didn't see anything. Then she get haunted by a girl when she gets home. The girl types on a computer you killed me or you hit me. Then remembering what happened she goes back to find the she hit a little girl and the girl drowned.

Another story is a boy was playing outside and pretending not to step on the circles. He gets distracted or someone calls his name and steps on the circle which turns out to be a snake and it bites him. I think all the circles were snakes.

Anyway the book is like a children/teenage ghost stories.

Answer (score 4):

I was searching for middle grade/young adult ghost stories, and just stumbled across this web site, and this question.

I actually know the answer, at least partially!

The first story you described is from a book of ghost stories by Vivian Vande Velde called *[Being Dead](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0152049126)*. The story is the first one in the book: "*Drop by Drop*."

I don't recognize the story about the boy and the snakes, however. I think it's from a different book, as I've read *Being Dead* recently and that story isn't in there. (Of course, "Drop by Drop" might have been reprinted in a different book of ghost stories, although I did a bit of googling and didn't come up with anything.)